# How to control the location tkinter window will center itself when the window gets dragged up

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a gui but ran into an issue with not knowing how to reform all the widget correctly so I decided to not allow any resizing. Now I just want the window to center itself when I drag the window to the top, and I looked up the event for this and I believe it is , but now the window keeps resetting itself to the original spot it pops up whenever I move the window. I only want it to reset when the window gets dragged to the top only

```
from tkinter import *


def move(e):  # 
    root.geometry("1270x725+0+0")


root = Tk()
root.geometry("1270x725+0+0")
root.resizable(False, False)
button = Button(root, command=move)
button.place(x=10, y=10)
Entry = Entry(root)
Entry.place(relx=.4, rely=.5)
root.bind('<Configure>', move)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's doing that because you hardcoded the window's position into the geometry string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `event.y` is smaller than a certain value. If it is smaller then, reset the position.

Here is an example:

```py
from tkinter import *


def move(e):  
    if e.y < 5:
        
        sw, sh = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
        root.geometry(f"1270x725+{(sw-1270)//2}+{(sh-725)//2}")


root = Tk()
root.geometry("1270x725+0+0")
root.resizable(False, False)

root.bind('<Configure>', move)

root.mainloop()
```